# will there complication to the body especially the guts, if basically a single senzu bean make a person never need to eat for the rest of their life?

Tags: science-based, food

this video surprisingly has some similar properties i try to make and better at explaining the science properties (without me knowing the science stuff before)

**warning!! don't watch the video when you are eating or in full stomach, there's a disgusting trivia in there**

[Dragon Ball Z’s 25,000-Calorie Diet | Because Science Footnotes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2e2OfSrhu8Y)

now my food version has some similar properties like [senzu bean](https://dragonball.fandom.com/wiki/Senzu_Bean) (mine doean't have a name yet) but more potent in the calories or nutrition not just filling for 10 days.

- its small like bean or pill.
- dense or hard (you cant chew/bite it).
- hard to digest but the micro part that get digested is enough to provide energy for full activity and even boost it with excess energy like in the state of adrenaline without actually in the state/activate adrenaline.
- fast/quick to rot if left out, maybe in a 5 minutes (even if you don't drop it).
- one full single food of this is enough calories and nutrition for a lifetime or even more (most not even fully digested even after the person die from old age or end of their lifespan), it basically mean no more need to eat for the rest of their life.
- eating more than one can lead to death from overdose, I assume something like their veins getting bulge blocking the blood flow or explode, including the explosion of several internal organs like heart for example.
- it mitigate appetite, but the person still can eat normal food if they really really desire or want to (its very rare), but it need controlled consumption/calories otherwise it can lead to the same overdose reactions or sudden obesity.
- because of the nutrition and calories, I assume it can boost a normal person lifespan.
- doesn't make people stay awake, so the person still need sleep or feel sleepy.
- doesn't regenerate body part for the consumer.
- wont mitigate pain.
- not heavy (I know in the video explanation such food should be massively heavy,but appreciate if there's a solution for that, without hand-wave it)
- wont feel hungry (because of the food size, I'm not sure will the feel of hunger still generate by body or not, so appreciate for further information or correction about this and others in the descriptions).

  so it just stronger compact food to fill hunger or energy for the rest of their life but not include thirst, the person still need to drink water.

**now my question is because of the food properties, will this also make a person doesn't need to poop/only generate almost nonexistence micro poop (excluding if they eat normal food so purely never eat anymore beside this food), or actually its the other way around?**

**if the person not generate poop or dump their feces, will this generate some complication to the body especially the intestines or stomach?**

**will the bacteria in the stomach or guts attack the body?**

Comment: The small problem is that the way the human body works it sheds mass continuously; that mass needs to be replaced from somewhere. Humans need more than energy and micronutrients to survive, otherwise we could live on a diet of sugar and vitamin pills.

Comment: @AlexP, you're often very much to the point in comments, but you shouldn't put partial answers in the comments, I'd like to see more full answers from you.

Comment: @Separatrix Not everyone has the time to flesh out a superb answer. Especially if it requires some proving via other sources. Comments are a great place to reveal problems.

Comment: You face the problem of physics. What is small yet have a lot of energy? Uranium for example. What if you consume uranium? You die. The more energy equal more mass. If you lower the size you end up in creating more and more powerful elements.

Comment: "because of the nutrition and calories, I assume it can boost a normal person lifespan" It might not. Studies have shown that slight starvation is more likely to boost lifespan. Full nutrition might not.

Answer (score 5):

The problem with this is that the human body is not evolved to retain an infinite nutrition bean.

You might swallow one of these beans, and it would provide all the nutrients you might need... until your body moved it through your stomach, into your intestines and then out of your rear-end, at which point it would cease being nutritious.  This would take between one and three days, that being the rate at which food passes through the human gut.

In the event that the infinite nutrition bean could not pass out of the stomach once it arrived there, the consequence of what is essentially free energy and biomass without any indigestible component would be that the usual abrasive action of normal food on the gut would be absent unless the person took care to eat high-fibre food in addition.  This in turn would have the consequence that bowel cancer would be very much more likely.  Normal people have a roughly 1 in 16 chance to develop bowel cancer, however this might increase to as much as 1 in 4, since cancerous cells would have very little chance of being abraded away before growing to the point where that would not ordinarily be possible.

Comment: yeah i realize it when i remember about corn....and i actually prepare the question regarding how to keep it stay in the stomach....still not upload it yet

Answer (score 4):

The way the bowels work, they continuously process the transiting food, extract nutrient and discharge remaining. Then the body, if cannot use the supplied energy, stores it in the form of fat.

The problem you might have as a consequence of assuming an extra large supply of energy in a single intake:

- large build up of fat: you are supplying way more than you are using, the excess will be stored.
- the bowels flora won't produce the oligo-elements it normally produces because of the lack of supply, so somehow the human would either need to integrate or suffer from lack of them
- build up of dead cells in the bowel: together with the expulsion of feces, the intestine also remove dead cells. If that doesn't happen, they might accumulate in loco, leading at least to imbalance in the bacterial flora.

Comment: so human still will generate feces from the dead cells? or the expulsion of feces is still very micro?or you mean expulsion of feces as throwing out the food through the anus? like undigested corn?

Answer (score 3):

Let's handwave the bean is magic so that it can produce all required nutrients "out of nothing" without being overly dense and without external supply. But there's nothing otherwise magical with it - it would be excreted out when eaten, as others explained.

So, to safely retain such a bean it's probably best if it is firmly attached to teeth, or placed in place of a tooth. The other, non-magical, teeth work best if they have fiber to chew, though. So it's best when the bean produces only carbohydrates, fats, vitamins and proteins, leaving fiber intake up to the user. Fiber is ubiquitous and lightweight, it's not a problem to carry [psyllium husks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psyllium) with, or chew on wood, hay, leaves or any other nontoxic plant material. As long as the fiber intake is maintained, I don't foresee any complications.

Comment: well i want it to stay in stomach kind of solution rather than visible or attached on the teeth though....but i apreciate the answer thanks.

Comment: So the bean recognizes the stomach lining as the ideal resting place and attaches itself to the lining, Since the lining is frequently replaced, attachment will have to be an ongoing process.

Answer (score 2):

**No chemical reactions are remotely energy dense enough to power a person for a lifetime.**

Nuclear fission fuel is roughly 1 million times as energy dense (1 gm U-235 has about the energy as 2 million g of oil or 3 million g of coal). 50 grams might be enough for a lifetime because you will have losses in whatever fuel cycle you invent.

You have to also figure out a way to distribute the energy through the body, and cope with the radiation damage centered on the bean.

Your bean needs to be made of nuclear fuel and the body re-engineered to operate on nuclear fuel. Not a trivial piece of engineering. People are chemical based for good reasons, my guess is that a reactor that produces chemical fuel by converting Water and CO2 into glucose or a similar process would be needed. You still need to deal with other essential elements, etc. even 99.99% effective recycling would still result in loss of critical materiel.

For example, where do you get calcium, etc. required for normal body function. Even if you replace bones by carbon nano-tubes or similar hand-wavium, some chemical reactions require very specific elements, not just CHON (the elements available from air and water). i.e., no sodium means no life. About the only hand-wavium I can think of is that water dissolves just about everything, and you drink a lot of chemical-laden water that you manage to scavange all needed elements from.

I assume the bean must attach itself somehow, or the body needs some additional engineering to retain the bean. Clearly the normal digestive system is useless for nuclear fuel, but you would still need it if you also want to process normal food.

Before you dismiss this as impossible, remember that this is essentially what chlorophyll does using photons as the power source.