# Is there a way to stop undigested food from leaving the body?

Tags: science-based, science-fiction, food

**WARNING PROBABLY CONTAINS DISGUSTING STUFF**

So base of my previous question about [will there complication to the body, especially the guts, if basically a single Senzu bean make a person never need to eat for the rest of their life?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/156677/will-there-complication-to-the-body-especially-the-guts-if-basically-a-single-s)

I just realized that such small and hard to digest food will probably end up like how a corn kernel follows the stool intact when nature calls, so even if the person does not generate poop, the body would probably move it to the intestines and do the natural thing on the undigested "food" in my previous question. And sure, you can eat it again after it goes through, like animals such as rabbits eating their feces, but I prefer not to, unless there's really no other solution.

I want to know whether there are any possible solutions for my hard to digest food to stay or remain in the human stomach forever (while still getting digested, so not stuck in the intestines either, but for example dissolve and spread out to entire body like fat or proteins is fine to me, as long their body doesn't become fat like fats do or like humans on steroids) without the body forcing it out undigested.

The solution can be change/remove or from the new food properties based on my previous question in the link (for example hard to digest into easy to digest, or it's sticky, or have some reaction with stomach acid or the stomach lining, to accommodate some solution as long as it maintains the infinite energy for the person, although I mention bean there, my food actually is not plant-based, it's just the size of a bean so imagine it as compressed food).

Modification or evolution of the organs to accommodate the bean is out as a solution or an answer, but normal reactions from the organs such as allergies or any reaction that makes them unable to excrement or puke the bean out is fine as long it make sense and does not end up killing the person or generating cancer.

Any answers with eating another 'new' bean are out because the food is limited and can't be re-created.

Comment: [Vermiform appendix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appendix_(anatomy)).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not make it that it absorbs water and expands in the stomach, then gradually dissolves over a period of years, releasing nutrients to be absorbed by the small intestines? The expansion means that it won't leave the stomach, and the nutrients, in liquid form, are absorbed into the body, so no waste is left behind.

This does not obviate the need for water! You'll need water to flush out accumulated waste from the body, including waste protein, cell detritus, bile etc. No infinite food source can replace that

Comment: This reminds me of another question (can't find it again) that asked about people that don't poop. The problem with that is that a lot of fecal matter *isn't* food, but dead gut bacteria, which is likely to still be around in this scenario. You hinted at this but didn't really elaborate; you need water to flush out the intestines, to urinate (urine is mostly waste products removed by the kidneys), and to replace water lost by sweating and/or bleeding. Possibly other reasons as well, but we can already see that you're in big trouble without water...

Comment: @Matthew: Not pooping isn't part of the scenario. It is only relevant insofar that the bean itself is not eliminated. Getting liquid nutrients without solid waste is to maximize the nutrient capacity of the bean, not to prevent pooping

Comment: All I was saying is that your comment about still needing water *reminded me* of that question. IOW, I was commenting on the nice, "antiseptic" phrasing you used ("flush out accumulated waste") and its translation into English that a four-year-old understands . (Hint: it involves two words that both start with 'p' followed by a double vowel.)

Answer (score 7):

I would suggest having the bean function as a **pseudo-parasite**.

Once the bean has entered the digestive system and been moved to the [appendix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appendix_(anatomy)), the unusually high concentration of bacteria and other life-forms causes it to 'awaken'.

It attaches itself to the walls of the appendix and sprouts roots into the blood stream, somehow cleverly warding off any attempt of the body to attack the foreign object.

Being directly connected to the blood supply, it can pump nutrition-rich substances into the body in a fast and efficient manner.

It's placement and small size allows the user to continue drinking and eating for pleasure, without having unpleasant side-effects.

Should the bean for some reason no longer be wanted, a medication can be consumed which weakens the bean, detaching the bean from the wall of the appendix and allowing it to exit the body naturally while the immune system fixes the damaged appendix wall.

Answer (score 4):

## Genetically Breed or Engineered Probiotics

Poop is not generated *only* from food.  You also poop out dead cells and other waste in the body; so if you don't eat food you *will* still have to poo.  What you need is a way to not only handle not only undigested food (which is often undigested because the body doesn't / can't process it!), but *also* to handle waste in general.

Bacteria have been successfully used [to eat poop in sewage](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/es201045e), and even [to clean up oil from spills](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a_HWlFzgQiM).  In fact, much of your digestive system already relies on foreign bacteria in your gut: pre-/pro-biotics.

There has been talk about genetically engineering bacteria to drink water and secrete concrete (for filling in holes in a cracked wall or foundation), and other random things.  Ignoring the possible doomsday scenarios (like an ocean turning into concrete), we'll stay focused on your question:

You need a bacteria that handles what the body cannot digest, what the body's waste has, and a way to turn that into something the body can use.  So, put the ideas together: a probiotic in the gut that feasts on these things, secreting pure water, minerals, or something else our bodies can regularly use (even simple glucose, ketones, or proteins).